# 'No matching constructor for initialization' Rad Studio 10 Clang Compiler

Tags: clang, c++builder, c++builder-xe8, c++builder-10-seattle

I have a snippet of code which compiles in C++ Builder XE8 using the classic BCC compiler.  However, in Rad Studio 10 Seattle using the Clang compiler I get the error

`'no matching constructor found for initialization of TChoiceItem'`

Here is the snippet of code which causes the error.

```
LISTITEM_BEGIN( sch_TYPE_Choice )
    LISTITEM_DATA( sch_TYPE_Daily,      "Daily" )
    LISTITEM_DATA( sch_TYPE_Weekly,     "Weekly" )
    LISTITEM_DATA( sch_TYPE_Monthly,    "Monthly" )
LISTITEM_END()
```

Here is the code which defines `TChoiceItem`

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define LISTITEM_BEGIN( Name ) TChoiceItem Name[] = {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define INT_LISTITEM_BEGIN( Name ) TIntChoiceItem Name[] = {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define LISTITEM_DATA( XCode, XText ) { XCode, 0, (char*)XText, 0 },
#define LISTITEM_DATA_NC( XShortText, XText ) { 0, (char*)XShortText, (char*)XText, 0 },
#define LISTITEM_DATA_EX( XCode, XShortText, XText ) { XCode, (char*)XShortText, (char*)XText, 0 },
#define LISTITEM_DATA_EX2( XCode, XShortText, XText, XDesc ) { XCode, (char*)XShortText, (char*)XText, (char*)XDesc },
#define LISTITEM_END() LISTITEM_DATA(0,0) };
```

I am fairly new to C++ so I am not exactly sure what to call the above method of defining a class/method.

Is this some sort of dated language feature not supported by the Clang compiler?  Is there a way to  modify the code or definition so the compiler will accept it?

Edit:

I found the actual declaration of the `TChoiceItem` class.

```
class TChoiceItem : public TChoiceBase
{
    public:
        char  Code;
        char *ShortText;
        char *Text;
        char *Desc;
};
```

It does't appear to have any sort of standard constructor at all.  But somehow, everything still compiles and works with the classic BCC compiler.

Edit 2:

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864967/no-matching-constructor-for-initialization-of-vectorstring-with-clang-3-2) which looks to be describing a similar issue.  Could it be that I need to include some kind of compiler flag when compiling the code?  If so can I add a flag somehow in the embarcadero project compiler settings?

Comment: What constructors does `TChoiceItem` have?

Comment: I included the definition of `TChoiceItem` in the original question.   From the definition, I don't see any constructors at all.

Comment: What about the constructors of `TChoiceBase`?

Comment: `TChoiceBase` has no constructors either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list of values in braces to initialize the individual members of a class or struct is known as [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

As explained on cppreference.com, aggregate initialization isn't permitted if the class has a base class (among other restrictions).  `TChoiceItem` inherits from `TChoiceBase`, so aggregate initialization isn't allowed (and the "classic" bcc32 compiler shouldn't have allowed it).

You have a couple of choices:

First, you can change the code to not inherit from `TChoiceBase`.

Second, you can define a constructor:

```
TChoiceItem(char code, char *short_text, char *text, char *desc)
    : Code(code), ShortText(short_text), Text(text), Desc(desc) {}
```

C++11's [uniform initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn387583.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) means that your macros' syntax doesn't have to change: instead of braces meaning a list of values for individual members, the braces will mean a list of parameters to the constructor, but the result will be the same.